# SSRS Report Builder How do I output everything in a string that comes before the last 18 characters?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reportbuilder

I have 3 Fields which all contain strings longer than 18 characters. They are Events, Merchandise and Memberships. Some examples of the codes are:

Merchandise 10-1066-1001-40503
Film Income 10-1066-1001-40497
Pantomime 10-1066-1001-40825

I need to output everything before the last 18 characters, so "Merchandise", "Film Income" etc.
The row is grouped on the different fields, so this works to get the full string:

`=Fields!StockItemAttributesPivot_Budget__Code.Value & Fields!EventAttributesPivot_Budget__Code__.Value & Fields!MembershipAttributesPivot_Budget__Code.Value`

I've managed to work out how to get the text before the last 18 characters as below:

`=Left(Fields!EventAttributesPivot_Budget__Code__.Value, Len(Fields!EventAttributesPivot_Budget__Code__.Value) -18)`

But as soon as I try to add this into a switch, I get #Error:

`=switch(Fields!EventAttributesPivot_Budget__Code__.Value <> "", Left(Fields!EventAttributesPivot_Budget__Code__.Value, Len(Fields!EventAttributesPivot_Budget__Code__.Value) -18), Fields!StockItemAttributesPivot_Budget__Code.Value <> "", Left(Fields!StockItemAttributesPivot_Budget__Code.Value, Len(Fields!EventAttributesPivot_Budget__Code__.Value) -18), Fields!MembershipAttributesPivot_Budget__Code.Value <> "", Left(Fields!MembershipAttributesPivot_Budget__Code.Value, Len(Fields!MembershipAttributesPivot_Budget__Code.Value) -18), Fields!EventAttributesPivot_Budget__Code__.Value like "*", "No Data")`

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the last expression/result pair. You can't (as far as I know) use `like` in expressions, this is not t-sql, it's a subset of VB.

If all you are trying to do is capture everything that is not captured in the first three expressions then simply replace

```
Fields!EventAttributesPivot_Budget__Code__.Value like "*", "No Data")
```

with

```
True, "No Data")
```

As `True` obviously always evaluates to `True` then this acts like an ELSE.

If I have misunderstood then please edit your question and explain the logic you are trying to create using `SWITCH()`